# Suse Enterprise Server 12 - Resize Root partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, suse, vmware-server

I have a Suse Enterprise Server 12 installed on a VMware server, I want to be able to increase the root volume, ideal I would like to be able to set it to auto expand. below is the layout.

```
df -h

Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/mapper/system-root   10G  8.4G  1.1G  89% /

udev                     916M  100K  916M   1% /dev

tmpfs                    916M  112K  916M   1% /dev/shm

/dev/sda1                 61M   43M   15M  75% /boot
```

Comment: do you have freespace on the virtual drive, and is it adjascent to the root partition? I see your \ is an encrypted LVM. whats the underlying filesystem?

Comment: Yes I have free space on the virtual drive.

Does this info make sense?

Disk /dev/sdb: 16.1 GB, 16111501312 bytes


   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1             128    25174143    12587008   8e  Linux LVM


   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *         128      128639       64256   83  Linux

 

Disk /dev/mapper/system-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

 
Disk /dev/mapper/system-swap doesn't contain a valid partition table

Comment: Add output of `pvdisplay -C` to your question. That will determine how much, if any, of your disks is available for growing logical volumes on the volume group "system". Also paste `/etc/fstab` (or otherwise let us know what filesystem you're using). The logical volume is easy to grow, see `man lvextend`, resizing the filesystem on top of the logical volume depends on the filesystem used.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up booting up with gparted and extending resizing the partition. Then in the Partition Manager I resized the partition, all worked fine. I tested it first in a cloned VM just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Commands to use: I believe your VG name is "system" and LV name is "root"

```
vgdisplay [VG name]
```

Look for the # PE's available and the size of the PEs and the amount of free space available.  This tells you how much more space you have to extend it by.

Let's say you want to extend by 5G and yo have it available

You can do:

```
 lvextend -L +5G [lvname] will increase it by 5 GB
```

Older kernels you would need to unmount to resize which means in your case you'd have to do it in maintenance mode and then do your

```
 resize2fs [LVNAME]
```

By the way the OS may not do it for you saying you need to run "e2fsck -f [LVNAME]" first.

Newer kernels you can resize on the fly

```
 resize2fs [LVNAME]
```

Hope that helps!